# Minimum Levenshtein distance with frequencies

Tags: c++

i new with c++ and i write code (with help) which calculate Levenshtein distance with to strings. I need to fix it so that it counts the distance and uses the frequencies as weights.

```
int getLevenshteinDistance(const string& source,
    const string& target,
    int insert_cost = 1,
    int delete_cost = 1,
    int replace_cost = 2)
{
    if (source.size() > target.size())
        return getLevenshteinDistance(target, source, delete_cost, insert_cost, replace_cost);


    const int min_size = source.size(), max_size = target.size();
    std::vector<int> lev_dist(min_size + 1);

    lev_dist[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= min_size; ++i)
        lev_dist[i] = lev_dist[i - 1] + delete_cost;


    for (int j = 1; j <= max_size; ++j)
    {
        int previous_diagonal = lev_dist[0], previous_diagonal_save;
        lev_dist[0] += insert_cost;

        for (int i = 1; i <= min_size; ++i)
        {
            previous_diagonal_save = lev_dist[i];
            if (source[i - 1] == target[j - 1])
                lev_dist[i] = previous_diagonal;
            else
                lev_dist[i] = std::min(std::min(lev_dist[i - 1] + delete_cost, lev_dist[i] + insert_cost), previous_diagonal + replace_cost);

            previous_diagonal = previous_diagonal_save;
        }
    }

    return lev_dist[min_size];
}
```

I have list of strings, for example [D
PN
LAD
S
RA
NP
AS
A
GPW
EGA
AQ
KY
FKG
GA
N
GPVSLGGLP
YR
G
PEAGPMISK
KGNN
GG
GPWM
NS
AGP
TDQNGG]

The weight of the removal/insertion is assumed to be equal to the frequency of the given string. The substitution, respectively, consists of the sum of the frequencies of the two strings.

I've got answer like 1
but right answer is 0.03
What i have do, to get float answer?

Comment: I do not really understand how to do this without losing the essence because I am not strong in c++. this is a standard function that calculates the Levenshtein distance, but it only uses the given values 1, 1, 2 as weights. I changed the question a little

Comment: That is a big problem. I can help you debug. Would that get you further?

Comment: yes it will help

Comment: Fine, just shrink it down into a [mre] and I'll do my best.

Comment: If you want your answer to be a float value, then first declare almost every datatype used, as float e.g. `vector<float> lev_list`. But all I see is your code performs addition & subtraction operations with `int` default values like 1,1,&2. In that case, how could your answer be a `float` value? In short, just change datatypes to `float` , or typecast the `int` type variables to `float` wherever necessary.

Comment: I can't compile it. If you want someone to help, make it into a small example that can be compiled